# How can I upload file to AspNet API from Angular

Tags: c#, angular, api, asp.net-core

Hello everyone I have tried everything but couldn't it. I want to upload image to aspNet API from Angular
can you help me more

that's my API code

```
 [HttpPost("add")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Add([FromForm] ImageDtos imageDtos)
        {

            return BadRequest();
        }
```

that's ImageDtos my object

```
  public class ImageDtos : IDto
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public IFormFile File  { get; set; }
    }
```

That's angular code my upload method

```
     addImage() {
    
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('Name', "aasdpkasjıdjs");
        formData.append('File', this.selectedFile);
        console.log(formData);
        this.httpClient.post("https://localhost:44348/api/carimages/add", formData).subscribe(response => {
    
        });

  }
```

that's html

```
 <form [formGroup]="carImageForm">

      <input type="file" formControlName="file"  style="margin-left: 50px;"  (change)="onFileSelected($event)">

    </form>
```

[that's my error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R2FrY.png)

Comment: do you have other api endpoints that work ?

Comment: thank you sir I fixed it. you gave me an idea. I didn't think this before. I have been trying for 6 hours. I am so grateful thank you. oh my dear stupid head.

Comment: no problem @Ghost, that why we all here)